# Can't copy a sheet due to restricted 'Temp' access

Tags: excel, vba

After a lot of reading on this site, it's now time to ask.
This is an error (1004 could not copy sheet) for which many questions and answers have been given, but still I cannot find a workable solution.

I created a tool for my colleague that will help in creating a CSV upload file.
The problem she is facing (works fine on my laptop) is that my code below wants to save a temporary file to "C:\Windows\Temp" (according to the IT guys at her office). This location is not accessible for reasons. The temp location which is accessible for all users would be: "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp". Where "xxx" is the user name, which is given in a cell named "USERNAME" (so this could be used to create a custom path to store temp files??).

This is my code:

```
    Sheets("CSV").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Options").Range("SAVELOCATION") & _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("options").Range("SAVENAME"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWindow.Close
```

I have tried to find various solutions, but I am limited by a lack of coding skill:

1. Save the sheet as new file without first copying it (to temp file) > no success with below code

```
    Sheets("CSV").SaveCopyAs Filename:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Options").Range("SAVELOCATION") & _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("options").Range("SAVENAME"), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

2. Changing the "temp" location > no idea how to.

I'd be grateful if anyone could help me out.

Lennard

Answer (score 0):

Use `savelocation = environ("TEMP")`
You could also save to My Documents, using:

```
Function MyDocs() As String
'returns the path to My Documents 
    MyDocs = CreateObject("wscript.shell").specialfolders("mydocuments")
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. SAVELOCATION is the path given in a cell (with reference "savelocation". This is where the final file will be saved. However, when I copy the sheet to a new file, before it is saved, it is saved in the temp folder.  Can I change this temp location somehow eith "environ("temp") ?